# Connecting to SharePoint using third party server via middleware Web API with CSOM

Tags: csom, webapi, sharepoint-app-registration

I'm developing a solution to connect from a third party API to SharePoint using a middleware. The following diagram shows how the architecture works.
[image]

In here, I want to connect with many customers in the middleware. There are separate SharePoint installations in customer side, where I don't have access.
I developed this for one customer according to this article. https://codedebate.com/2020/07/21/access-and-consume-a-sharepoint-online-custom-list-from-an-asp-net-web-api-using-csom-and-bearer-access-tokens/

My requirement is to get files from given document library/libraries in the SharePoint to Web API through this middleware, and also I need to save the files in SharePoint document library which sends from Web API.

According to the above article, customer need to create an app in SP site by defining permission scopes and access rights to document libraries and then I need get and save Client Id and Client Secret of that app in my middleware. I thought to use a DB to store these data, since I need to manage many customers.

Question : Is this a good approach?

Having Client Id and Client Secret of the created app in the middleware, any user with access to middleware can access SP as well. They don't want to be a user in SP.

Question : How to authenticate the requests from middleware to SP ?

Note : Customer 1 will access Web API ( Website) and customer will send a get request to middleware to fetch files in SP 1 document library. Middleware needs to identify the customer with the request and get app details from DB accordingly to make connection to SP.

Comment: Still looking for an answer to design high level architecture. I'm pretty much new to this content.